# console-browserify error while building on fleek, ive tried everything

Tags: reactjs

10:52:44 AM 06/25/2022: Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /workspace/node_modules/console-browserify/index.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
10:52:44 AM 06/25/2022: You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
10:53:08 AM 06/25/2022: Error occured during the build.

Comment: have you tried  to Symlink the package folder?
`npm link [<package-spec>]` documentations [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link)

Comment: i have, didnt work